# How to set a meta quest 2 app icon using Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculusquest, appicon

I am trying to set up a meta quest 2 app icon for my app. I am using meta for business to push the app to the headset. It does show up as an app, however it only has the name of the app on the icon, not the actual icon I want to use.

I have tried to change every icon within unity, and it seems to still not change the icon on the meta app. I am using dropbox to host the apk file, then meta for business pulls it down and puts the apk on the headset. I am using the android platform. I have changed the default icon, the default cursor, the icon under the settings for android, including all the adaptive, round, and legacy icons. I have also changed the splash image and added a logo, background image, alternate portrait image, and static splash image as well.